# Laravel relationships, need advice

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm working on a project where I use Laravel 8/Eloquent to and I have the following models and relationships:
[image]

A project have many scenarios and a scenario belong to a tag.

I received a new requirement, some of the tags can be used only once per project(for only one scenario).

My approach is to add a new column to the tags table called "unique", in this way I know that this tag can be used only once:

```
id | name        | unique | created_at
-----------------------------------------
1  | ADPDF       | false  | 2017-01-30 13:22:39
-----------------------------------------
2  | ADPDF_FINAL | true   | 2017-01-30 13:23:42
```

I'm using TagController to send to the client all the tags, now I need a way to send only the tags that are not-unique or tags tat are unique and not used.

My current controller method:

```
public function index(Request $request) {

   return TagResource::collection(Tag::all());
}
```

Relationships:

```
class Project extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Historyable;


    public function scenarios() {
        return $this->hasMany(Scenario::class);
    }

}

class Scenario extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Historyable;

    public function tag() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Tag::class);
    }
}

class Tag extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function scenarios() {
        return $this->hasMany(Scenario::class);
    }
}
```

Any ideea how I can approach this? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: could you post your relation models

Comment: You could do this `TagResource::distinct()->get(['column_name']);`

Comment: @Basharmal, I added relationships

Answer (score 0):

First of all, fetching not-unique tags are fairly simple:

```
Tag::where('unique', false)->get();
```

To get not-used unique tags can be a heavy operation if you have too many tags. That's why it can be a good idea to add a new column to tags table called "used" and make it true when it's used. Then fetch them easily:

```
Tag::where([['unique', '=', true], ['used', '=', false])->get();
```

If you make the new column nullable add set null if not-unique, your query will be simpler:

```
Tag::where('used', false)->get();
```

If you don't want to add a new column, you need to fetch all unique tags with scenarios and count them.

```
Tag::whewre('unique', true)
  ->with('scenarios')
  ->get()
  ->filter(function($tag) {
    return $tag->scenarios->count() == 0;
  });
```

Actually, Laravel has a helper for this operation, but I can't remember it. If I find, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I don't think I can use the "used" flag, because the tags are unique only by project, so the unique flag can be use also in another project.